# Any operations for ImageView inside listitem in a listview not working - Android

Tags: android, listview

This seems very weird, may be I am missing something please help me.
I have an image in a listitem in a listview and I am trying to set bitmap but it is not working.
Code where I am setting the Bitmap:

```
MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) context;
        //  FragmentManager fmanager = activity.getFragmentManager();

            ListFragment fragment = activity.getCurrentFragment();
            Adapter adapter = fragment.getListView().getAdapter();


            int counter = 0;
            for (String key: logoAndCorrespondingPosition.keySet()){

                View x = adapter.getView(logoAndCorrespondingPosition.get(key), null, null);
                //logoAndCorrespondingPosition.
                ImageView xx = (ImageView) x.findViewWithTag(key);
                TextView xy = (TextView) x.findViewById(R.id.listitem_brand_with_offers_brandName);

                if (xy!=null)
                    xy.setText("asdasdsdas");

                byte[] logoBytes = response.ResponseResult1.get(counter);

                if (logoBytes!=null){
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(logoBytes, 0, logoBytes.length);
                    //xx.setImageResource(R.color.transparent);
                    xx.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
                counter++;
            }
```

Yes, I am accessing this listview after it has been populated as I am filling the blank images with bitmap value.
Interestingly, on debugging, none of the views (Image and Text, code above) returns null, they have a value associated with them, in spite of it the settext and setimagebitmap never works.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Debug the value of `logoBytes` for null.

Comment: Then debug the value of `bitmap`. It seems that it is not been decoded properly to create a bitmap.

Comment: @Ravi: It is perfectly valid bitmap, even xy.setText doesnt work and xy is not null.

Comment: call setImageBitmap() only in Adapter.getView()

Comment: @pskink: I tried that first and it works but this blank images needs to be filled with a bitmap I retrieve from WCF call, if I place that call (which is asynctask) in getView() its firing many duplicate requests (which I handled using hashmaps) but then in onPostExecute the imageView.setBitmap(..) gets assigned to random images at random positions

Comment: no,  you get it wrong, call your async task wherever you want,  when you receive the results update your adapter's data model (updating the bitmaps) and finally call adapter.notifyDatasetChanged, it will in result call getView again this time with updated data

Comment: @pskink: Alright mate, I will try and will comment back. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's bad idea to fill images outside of adapter. It's important to understand how adapter works. When you call getView() method of adapter, adapter binding existing view (or creating new) to display on the screen. If you try to call method getView() for position, which is not displaying on the screen, adapter will return the first view on screen. (if you properly working with convertView). That's why you can set bitmap outside adapter only for items, which are on the screen now. There some techniks to do what you want:

Get image in getView(). In this case, you must controll, that your imageview still on screen and not reused, while scrolling. It's happening because, while you loading data, user can scroll and this list item reused. Your imageView still exist, but situated in another position. To prevent this, you can setTag() for your image view inside bindView with position. And on post execute check tag of your imageView with your value. For exaple:

```
View bindView(final View v, int position) {
  final String url = "url to bitmap";
  ImageView iv = <get image view>;
  iv.setTag(url);
  new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {
     Bitmap doInBackground(Void... void) {
        Bitmap bitmap = <load your bitmap>;
        return bitmap;
     }



void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
     if (iv.getTag().equals(url)) 
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
 } 

  }
  return view;
}
```

Note, i wrote this code right here and it's pseudocode to show idea.

The second way is to use lib like [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso). It will all this work for you.

Comment: This is what I am currently doing, in adapter.getView() I am associating a unique tag for imageviews and recording the row position, and at the end calling Asynctask, In onPostExecute for that row(position I previously recorded) I am retrieving imageview using the unique tags --> This returns me the image view I am interested in but setBitmap or setText has no effect on.

Comment: don't do that,  it's tricky, the normal way is as described above in my comment

Comment: @pskink your idea with notifyDataSetChange has only one huge problem. You need to store all images in memory and if your list will long enough you get OutOfMemory. Or you need to clean images in yourself. In my case you don't need to do this, because you don't have strong reference to images outside of imageView and it will be cleaned as image not displayed.

Comment: @Avais post your adapter code. I think you have mistake somewhere.

Comment: @Avais if you want data on demand (no caching in any lists) you could see and modify PagedCursor https://gist.github.com/pskink/b21c932f405740011144 and the test content provider https://gist.github.com/pskink/9ab862cdd0d6b0281ab4

Comment: Alright guys I solved it using calling notifyDataSetAdapter after I update values from web service call. Thanks for your comments and time :)